# how to attach a domain to a sub domain of particular website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, digital-ocean

I am working on a E-shop-enabler web side using rails 3.2. when a user come to our side and create a shop then we provide a sub domain to that user like XYZ.OURSITEURL.COM. if my user want his own domain like WWW.XYZ.COM who can i attach that Domain to my sub domain.I have no idea how to do do this.I deploy my project on digital ocean. using rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Your user who has his domain WWW.XYZ.COM provided by some domain hosting provider needs to add a CNAME record for his domain to be mapped to the subdomain (XYZ.OURSITEURL.COM) that you provide